# Modularized Maven-Spring Project Dilemma

Tags: maven, web-applications, module

I work for a big organization and we came up with a big application (web).

We started from a very small application but now it turned into a big heap of java code which has 3 interfaces.

1. Front-End
2. An Admin Panel
3. A Blogging Part.

Till now, we were doing all that in one project by making different packages, but now we want that if one any one part is removed, the functionality of the application should remain intact.

I tried to make maven based modules and divide the code into them, but ended up creating *directories* inside the core module.

Our current directory structure is; [image]

We want to create something like this;[image]

And when compiled, the modules should go into one directory, i.e, the tomcat web application folder.

Can this be achieved using the maven plugins or I have to do some extra amendments on my level?

#### EDIT:-

I also nees the web.xml files to he merged.

Comment: For deploying to Tomcat you could try the [Tomcat-Maven-Plugin](https://tomcat.apache.org/maven-plugin-2.0/tomcat7-maven-plugin/), not 100% sure if it covers your case

Comment: I forgot to mention. But i also need the web.xml files to me merged.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I required was accomplished by defining a custom MOJO.

### Off Topic:

The tool is almost complete and would be available to fork as an open source project. ;)

Answer (score 0):

I seems like you need to take "maven multi-module" projects paradigm into the use. Did you think about it already?

P.S. Although Maven's multi module approach will produce three separate WAR artifacts. Did you think about separating your big app into three modules?

Comment: Yep. I am already using the maven multi module projects. Specifically, I don't actually need to build 3 different WARs. I just want the actual webapp (including these three modules) to be built in a specific *target* folder.

Comment: It came to my mind, that there is "overlay" feature in maven-war-plugin (https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-war-plugin/overlays.html). Maybe it helps you to merge three WAR artifacts into one WAR artifact.

Comment: Thanks. Ended up building a custom mojo. Lol