# How to make maven copy all classes from another project?

Tags: java, maven, jpa, classpath

I have a number of Entity classes in a shared project.

In order to get JPA working properly, I need these class files in the classes folder and not inside the jar.

How would I go about doing this in maven?
Is there a specific maven plugin I can use?

### Source:

```
project1/src/main/java/org/something/SomeClass.java

project2/src/main/java/org/somethingElse/SomeEntity.java
```

Target:

```
project1/target/classes/org/something/SomeClass.java
project1/target/classes/org/somethingElse/SomeEntity.java
```

Alternative approaches are also OK.

### Update:

Use Case:

I have multiple projects.
One project is the core library for all things shared.
This includes a bunch of entity classes that have PersistanceUnit Entity Managers injected.

The issue arises when i try to use these entity classes because the entity manager is no longer injected. Additionally when I manually specify the entity manager, it doesn't recognize any of the entity classes in the shared jar.

Comment: Do you want to copy classes like the title and body are saying, or the source files, like the example is showing?

Comment: I wan't the compiler (including the aspectj weaving to be able to see the java files as if they were part of the same project.

Comment: I did not understand that. Can you edit with your exact use-case, what you have, and what you want? How and when is aspectj coming to the table?

Comment: I think that you're developing a project with multiple modules and want to *merge* them when you are doing your build tasks... You can refer to [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35355029/modularized-maven-spring-project-dilemma) post if you want to...

Comment: That is exactly what I want to do.

Answer (score 1):

Try 
[Unpacking specific artifacts](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/examples/unpacking-artifacts.html)

Sample config from docs:

> ```
> <project>
>    [...]
>    <build>
>      <plugins>
>        <plugin>
>          <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
>          <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
>          <version>2.10</version>
>          <executions>
>            <execution>
>              <id>unpack</id>
>              <phase>package</phase>
>              <goals>
>                <goal>unpack</goal>
>              </goals>
>              <configuration>
>                <artifactItems>
>                  <artifactItem>
>                    <groupId>junit</groupId>
>                    <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
>                    <version>3.8.1</version>
>                    <type>jar</type>
>                    <overWrite>false</overWrite>
>                    <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/alternateLocation</outputDirectory>
>                    <destFileName>optional-new-name.jar</destFileName>
>                    <includes>**/*.class,**/*.xml</includes>
>                    <excludes>**/*test.class</excludes>
>                  </artifactItem>
>                </artifactItems>
>                <includes>**/*.java</includes>
>                <excludes>**/*.properties</excludes>
>                <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/wars</outputDirectory>
>                <overWriteReleases>false</overWriteReleases>
>                <overWriteSnapshots>true</overWriteSnapshots>
>              </configuration>
>            </execution>
>          </executions>
>        </plugin>
>      </plugins>
>    </build>
>    [...]
>  </project>
> ```

Comment: This would work except that the aspectj weaving doesn't get done.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to use **[copysource-maven-plugin](https://github.com/bytemechanics/copysource-maven-plugin)**:

```
(...)
<build>
   <plugins>
      (...)
      <plugin>
         <groupId>org.bytemechanics.maven</groupId>
         <artifactId>copysource-maven-plugin</artifactId>
         <version>X.X.X</version>
         <executions>
            <execution>
               <goals>
                  <goal>copy-classes</goal>
               </goals>
               <configuration>
                  <copies>
                     <copy>
                        <artifact>[source-groupId]:[source-artifactId]:[source-version]</artifact>
                        <classes>
                           <class>[cannonical-name-of-origin-source. Example:org.bytemechanics.commons.functional.LambdaUnchecker]</class>
                           (...)
                        </classes>
                        <fromPackage>[package-segment-to-replace. Example: org.bytemechanics.commons]</fromPackage>
                        <toPackage>[package-segment-to-replace. Example: org.bytemechanics.standalone.ignite.internal.commons]</toPackage>
                     </copy>
                  </copies>
               </configuration>
            </execution>
         </executions>
      </plugin>     
      (...)
    </plugins>
</build>    
(...)
```